# I know the equation for curvature for y=f(x). Can we extend this result to z=f(x,y)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

From wikipedia, for a plane curve given by $y=f(x)$ $\kappa$ is:
$$\kappa = \frac{y''}{{(1+y'^2)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Can we find a formula for a function $z=f(x,y)$?

Comment: For surfaces, there are different curvatures to consider. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces#Curvature_of_surfaces_in_Euclidean_space

Answer (score 1):

Consider a vertical rotating plane that contains the line of parametric equation

$$x=x_0+t\cos\theta,\\
y=y_0+t\sin\theta.$$

Plugging it in the equation of the surface, we get the equation of the intersection curve

$$z=f(x_0+t\cos\theta, y_0+t\sin\theta)$$ of which we can compute the curvature, using
$$z'=\cos\theta f'_x+\sin\theta f'_y$$ and

$$z''=\cos^2\theta f''_{xx}+2\cos\theta\sin\theta f''_{xy}+\sin^2\theta f''_{yy}.$$

Then

$$\kappa_\theta=\frac{\cos^2\theta f''_{xx}+2\cos\theta\sin\theta f''_{xy}+\sin^2\theta f''_{yy}}{(1+(\cos\theta f'_x+\sin\theta f'_y)^2)^{3/2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Sure. For any point $p$ and tangent vector $v$ on your surface, $\gamma(t)=z(p+vt)$ is a curve on your surface and plugging $\gamma$ into your formula gives you a notion of curvature (normal curvature) of your surface. Notice that this curvature depends on $v$.